# Vue: Array is only updated on console, not on screen

Tags: arrays, vue.js, components

I'm still learning the basics of vue. I have different elements in one component, that have to be assigned in a second component. When I use console.log the array is shown correctly, but when i want to show the array in dynamically in template it is still the default value. What am I doing wrong?

Component one:

```
    <template>
    <div>
{{nr}}
{{containertyp}}
      <button  @click="click(0)"></button>
</div>
     </template>
```

I have many more buttons with different parameters, just to make it shorter here.

```
export default: {
data: function {
return {
nr: [],
containertyp: [],
    }
    }
methods: {
  click(number) {

    for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
      this.nr[i] = false;
      if (number == i) {
        this.nr[i] = true;
      }
    };

    EventBus.$emit('containerclicked');

  }
},
created: function() {
  let i;
  //default
  for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    this.nr[i] = false; 
  }
  for (var index = 0; index < 27; index++) {
    this.containertyp[index] = 'bs';
  }
},
mounted() {

  const self = this
  EventBus.$on('containertypchosen', function (containertyp) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
      if (self.nr[j] == true) {
        self.containertyp[j] = containertyp
      }
    }
  })
```

Component two:

```
<template>
<div>
<button :disabled = "disabled == true"  v-on:click="chosetype('bs')" "> bs </button> <br />
</div>
</template>
export default: {
data: function() {
return {
disabled: true
}
}
     mounted () {
    const self = this
    EventBus.$on('containerclicked', function (){
      self.disabled = false

    })
  },
methods: {
chosetype: function (containertyp) {
      this.containertyp = containertyp
      EventBus.$emit('containertypchosen', containertyp)
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update arrays using indexes, the changes won't be detected by the reactivity system.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

So, for example, this won't work:

```js
this.nr[i] = true;
```

Instead you'd need to use `Vue.set`, or the alias `vm.$set`:

```js
this.$set(this.nr, i, true);
```

An alternative would be to create a new array and then replace `this.nr` entirely, i.e. `this.nr = newArray`.

You'll need to make a similar change everywhere that you're updating an array by index. There are updates to both `nr` and `containertyp` that currently have this problem.

It's not immediately clear from your code whether `nr` even needs to be an array. It seems that all the values are `false` apart from one, so you might be better off just holding the index of the `true` value instead of using an array.